# Remove unnecessary quotes from CSV fields

Tags: c#, csv, apex, apex-code

I have a CSV file that was formatted in a way, so each value is in double quotes.

The CSV Reader that I'm using is not able to properly read a file formatted like this. According to it, the double quotes should only be in values where there's a comma, or there's an actual double quote in the field value.

Is there a quick & safe way to remove all double quotes that are unnecessary?

The CSV Reader that I'm using is the following IETF RCF 4180 compliant reader from Marty Chang: https://github.com/martyychang/sfdc-csv

Comment: May you provide an sample data, edited. from the file directly. the map class and the configuration used? Like a [mre], for now we have the description of a string that we can only imagine. And dev imagination is full edge case scenario. An input and the expected output covering most of case will be cool.

Comment: And RFC 4180, 2. Definition of the CSV Format  5 says : "_5.  Each field **may or may not be enclosed in double quotes** (however
       some programs, such as Microsoft Excel, do not use double quotes
       at all).  If fields are not enclosed with double quotes, then
       double quotes may not appear inside the fields.  For example:

       "aaa","bbb","ccc" CRLF
       zzz,yyy,xxx_"

Comment: Respective GitHub Ticket https://github.com/martyychang/sfdc-csv/issues/6

Comment: And I will recommend using https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper  https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/ . It does that out of the box.